# How to construct a matrix with given l2 norm requirement?

Tags: matrices

Can somebody tell me how to construct a matrix satisfying $\vert \vert A \vert \vert_2 <1 $?

Note that the norm is defined as $\vert \vert A \vert \vert_2 = \sqrt{ \lambda_{max} (A^T A)} $.

Are there any good theorems making this design process deterministic?

Comment: example $A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0& \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: For a process take any $B\neq 0$ and define $A:= \frac{B}{||B||_2+\varepsilon}$, $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks! Why does this work? Any reference?

Comment: What do you mean by why?

Comment: Why is it guaranteed that this process gives an A with $\vert \vert A \vert \vert_2 <1 $?

Comment: Are there rules if I change the problem to $\vert \vert A \vert \vert_p <1 $

Comment: For any norm we have $||A||= ||\frac{B}{||B||+\varepsilon}||= \frac{||B||}{||B||+\varepsilon}<1$